# When storing AWS load balancer logs in S3, how do I pass the S3 prefix to Loki when using lambda-promtail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana-loki, promtail

I am ingesting application load balancer logs into Loki using lambda-promtail. This works great, however, the default labels only include the account and load balancer ID. I would like to use the S3 prefix as a label to use as variable in Grafana (I could use the domain as a filter but this doesn't really work for my use case).

I have searched through the docs and Github but have been unable to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promtail does not send the S3 `key` or `prefix` by default. You need to modify the Lambda code yourself. I added an example implementation but haven't tested it myself.

Firstly, [extracting the prefix from the S3 event](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/6385b195739bd7d4e9706faddd0de663d8e5331a/tools/lambda-promtail/lambda-promtail/s3.go#L239).

```go
func getLabels(record events.S3EventRecord) (map[string]string, error) {

    labels := make(map[string]string)

    labels["key"] = record.S3.Object.Key

    // Define a regular expression to find the prefix before "AWSLogs"
    prefixRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*?)AWSLogs`)
    prefixMatch := prefixRegex.FindStringSubmatch(labels["key"])
    // The first submatch is the entire match, and the second one is the captured group
    labels["prefix"] = prefixMatch[1]

    labels["bucket"] = record.S3.Bucket.Name
    labels["bucket_owner"] = record.S3.Bucket.OwnerIdentity.PrincipalID
    labels["bucket_region"] = record.AWSRegion
    for key, p := range parsers {
        if p.filenameRegex.MatchString(labels["key"]) {
            if labels["type"] == "" {
                labels["type"] = key
            }
            match := p.filenameRegex.FindStringSubmatch(labels["key"])
            for i, name := range p.filenameRegex.SubexpNames() {
                if i != 0 && name != "" && match[i] != "" {
                    labels[name] = match[i]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if labels["type"] == "" {
        return labels, fmt.Errorf("type of S3 event could not be determined for object %q", record.S3.Object.Key)
    }
    return labels, nil
}
```

Then [adding the prefix as a label](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/6385b195739bd7d4e9706faddd0de663d8e5331a/tools/lambda-promtail/lambda-promtail/s3.go#L159).

```go
func parseS3Log(ctx context.Context, b *batch, labels map[string]string, obj io.ReadCloser, log *log.Logger) error {
    parser, ok := parsers[labels["type"]]
    if !ok {
        if labels["type"] == CLOUDTRAIL_DIGEST_LOG_TYPE {
            return nil
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("could not find parser for type %s", labels["type"])
    }
    gzreader, err := gzip.NewReader(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(gzreader)

    ls := model.LabelSet{
        model.LabelName("__aws_log_type"):                                   model.LabelValue(parser.logTypeLabel),
        model.LabelName("__aws_s3_prefix"):                                   model.LabelValue(labels["prefix"]),
        model.LabelName(fmt.Sprintf("__aws_%s", parser.logTypeLabel)):       model.LabelValue(labels["src"]),
        model.LabelName(fmt.Sprintf("__aws_%s_owner", parser.logTypeLabel)): model.LabelValue(labels[parser.ownerLabelKey]),
    }

    ls = applyLabels(ls)

  // ...
}
```

The data sent by default with `lambda-promtail` are the log line from the S3 object and attached labels, for example:

- `__aws_log_type = s3_lb` The service that created the log
- `__aws_s3_lb = my-alb`: The resource that created the log
- `__aws_s3_lb_owner = 123456789`: The AWS account ID of the S3 bucket.

You can also attach static hardcoded values in [EXTRA_LABELS](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/6385b195739bd7d4e9706faddd0de663d8e5331a/tools/lambda-promtail/lambda-promtail/main.go#L57).